# Sound recognition for Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, fft, sound-recognition

I am creating an Android application using Phonegap. I would like to record a sound (for example, a doorbell), and detect if that sound is heard again. Is there any sound recognition plugin for Phonegap?

If not, how can I access the frequencies of the recorded sound (for example, in an array), so I can manually write an algorithm to compare the two audio files? Is there any audio format which stores data in that form?

Thank you

Comment: for recording you can use: https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin

Comment: I am using that for voice recognition. Would that work for audio recording? Alao, my problem isn't finding a plugin to record audio. It's finding one for recognizing audio